# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at validatename_degree

Tags: javascript, html

I have already seen the pages here for this error, but neither `window.load` nor putting script in the div block have solved it. If I write `document.getElementById("fullname_error")`, it is working, but it is not working with `document.getElementById(ident)` though the `var ident` is equal to the id of p , I have checked it.

```
<div class="most_page">
    <div id="form_container" >
        <form action="register.php" method="post" name="reg_doc">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>Full name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fullname" value="Full name" ></td>
                    <td><p id="fullname_error" > hh</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="address" onkeypress='validatename_degree(fullname.value,fullname_error.id);' value="Address"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button class="button" id="submitreg" ><input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit"></button>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function validatename_degree(x,ident) {
                    var iden='"'+ident+'"';
                    document.getElementById(iden).innerHTML=iden;
                }
            </script>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should fix your eval mentality. `iden = eval('"'+ident+'"')` may work (or not) but definitely it's bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require `var iden='"'+ident+'"';` just use `var iden=ident;`. Please try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <div class="most_page">
        <div id="form_container">
            <form action="register.php" method="post" name="reg_doc">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Full name</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="fullname" value="Full name">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p id="fullname_error"> hh</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="address" onkeypress='validatename_degree(fullname.value,fullname_error.id);' value="Address">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button class="button" id="submitreg">
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
                </button>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function validatename_degree(x, ident) {
                        var iden = ident;
                        document.getElementById(iden).innerHTML = iden;
                    }
                </script>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: THANKS buddy , spend an hour figuring out the error . Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. If this is the solution you require, please approve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the parameter ident to the document.getElementById property and use the your existing code,below is a working snippet

```html
<div class="most_page">
    <div id="form_container" >
        <form action="register.php" method="post" name="reg_doc">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>Full name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fullname" value="Full name" ></td>
                    <td><p id="fullname_error" > hh</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="address" onkeypress='validatename_degree(fullname.value,fullname_error.id);' value="Address"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button class="button" id="submitreg" ><input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit"></button>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function validatename_degree(x,ident) {
                  console.log(""+ident)
                    var iden='"'+ident+'"';
                    document.getElementById(ident).innerHTML=iden;
                }
            </script>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```